# Счётчик кликов для разных блоков через делегирование JS

Tags: javascript

Есть  код который   название блока и считает клики по кнопке.
Проблема в том что поле с  количеством кликов меняется один раз. С 0 до 1  и все. Подскажите в чем проблема

```
(function () {
  var buttons = document.querySelector('#list');
  buttons.onclick = function (e) {
   var clicks = 0;
   clicks++;
   var target = e.target;
   if (target.tagName = 'BUTTON') {

  var counter = target.closest('li').querySelector('.product-item__counter');
  counter.innerHTML = clicks;

  var product = target.closest('li').querySelector('.product-item__title').innerHTML;
  alert(' You have bought a ' + product);
 }
 };
})();
```

Пример https://jsfiddle.net/dedn/60b6uL4c/

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы. Все очень подробные, и все мне помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var clicks = 0;` Здесь вы сбрасываете текущее значение счётчика и начинаете сначала.

Ну и, у каждого счётчика должно быть своё хранилище текущего значения.

`if (target.tagName = 'BUTTON') {` - Здесь вы ничего не проверяете, оператор присваивания возвращает truthy значение.

---

Можно выбрать все элементы([querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) и навешать отдельный обработчик на каждый.
В качестве хранилища текущего значения счётчика можно использовать само отображаемое значение:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul .btn')
  .forEach(function(el){ 
    el.onclick = function() {
      let cnt = this.closest('li').querySelector('.cnt');
      cnt.innerText = parseInt(cnt.innerText, 10)+1;
    };
  });
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
    <span class="cnt">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
    <span class="cnt">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
    <span class="cnt">0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Или с общим для всех обработчиком(по аналогии с вашим):

```js
document.querySelector('ul').onclick = function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName != 'BUTTON') return;
  let cnt = target.closest('li').querySelector('.cnt');
  cnt.innerText = parseInt(cnt.innerText, 10)+1;
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
    <span class="cnt">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
    <span class="cnt">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
    <span class="cnt">0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.   Я  как раз  хотел сделать с общим обработчиком как вы указали в примере.  Подскажите ещё для чего в этой строке             cnt.innerText = parseInt(cnt.innerText, 10)+1;    цифра 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons.onclick = function (e) {
    var clicks = 0;
    clicks++;
```

Все дело в том, что вы не сохраняете состояние. Каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку, у вас обнуляется счетчик и он же повышается на +1. Простой путь это проверить - поставить так `var clicks = 0;debugger;` и вы увидите, что после нажатия кнопки у вас `clicks` всегда равен 0.

Решение простое - вам нужно вынести объявление clicks вне функции нажатия. Однако у вас тогда будет один счетчик на все кнопки. Можно сохранить значение clicks для каждой кнопки отдельно в самом html например (не самый лучший вариант).

UPD

Посмотрел внимательней и обнаружил кое-что.

1) [Смотрим тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) по поводу querySelector, а именно на деталь, что он вернет **только** первый элемент.

2) Во вторых - почему у вас buttons это вдруг оказался `<ul class="list" id="list">` ?? Это абсолютно неверно т.к. нажимая куда угодно мы получаем вызов функции ( не только на кнопку). Ваша переменная вводит в заблуждение. Если вы хотите обрабатывать кнопки, то повесьте на них класс и ищите с помощью селектора классов `.someClass` [тык](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom#getelementsbyclassname).

3) Вот накидал по шустрому (тапками не бить плз). Используя замыкание, мы получаем на каждой кнопке свой счетчик.

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  return function() {
    return currentCount++;
  };
};
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('ss1');
var clicker = function(e) {
  var value = this.counter();
  console.log(this.defaultValue + " - " + value);
};

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].counter = makeCounter();
  buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
    clicker.apply(this);
  };
}
```

```html
<div> <input type="button" id="1" class="ss1" text="s" value="haha"> </div>
<div> <input type="button" id="2" class="ss1" value="haha1"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `localStorage` примерно так:

```js
(function() {
  var clicks = 0;
  var buttons = document.querySelector('#list');
  buttons.onclick = function(e) {
    clicks = clicks ? localStorage.getItem(e.target.id) : 0;
    clicks++;
    localStorage.setItem(e.target.id, clicks);
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.tagName = 'BUTTON') {

      var counter = target.closest('li').querySelector('.list-item__counter');
      counter.innerHTML = clicks;

      var product = target.closest('li').querySelector('.list-item__title').innerHTML;
      alert(' You have bought a ' + product);
    }
  };
})();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">List</h1>
  <ul class="list" id="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <h2 class="list-item__title">Title First</h2>
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam dolorum exercitationem harum ipsam modi nesciunt optio qui quia quidem reiciendis? Alias consectetur dolorem hic nobis optio quam quos sapiente veniam.</p>
      <button id="bt1" class="list-item__click-btn">btn</button>
      <span class="list-item__counter">0</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <h2 class="list-item__title">Title Second</h2>
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam dolorum exercitationem harum ipsam modi nesciunt optio qui quia quidem reiciendis? Alias consectetur dolorem hic nobis optio quam quos sapiente veniam.</p>
      <button id="bt2" class="list-item__click-btn">Btn</button>
      <span class="list-item__counter">0</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <h2 class="list-item__title">Title Third</h2>
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam dolorum exercitationem harum ipsam modi nesciunt optio qui quia quidem reiciendis? Alias consectetur dolorem hic nobis optio quam quos sapiente veniam.</p>
      <button id="bt3" class="list-item__click-btn">btn</button>
      <span class="list-item__counter">0</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <h2 class="list-item__title">Title Fourth</h2>
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam dolorum exercitationem harum ipsam modi nesciunt optio qui quia quidem reiciendis? Alias consectetur dolorem hic nobis optio quam quos sapiente veniam.</p>
      <button id="bt4" class="list-item__click-btn">Btn</button>
      <span class="list-item__counter">0</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка отображает кол-во раз, которое по ней кликнули, обновляется при каждом клике:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.button');

function hendleBtnClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
  let counteClickBtn = btn.textContent;
  btn.textContent = parseInt(counteClickBtn) + 1;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', hendleBtnClick);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  min-width: 88px;
  min-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 64px;
  vertical-align: top;

  font-size: 64px;
  color: #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;

  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;

  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: background-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Module 9 Practice 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <button class="button">0</button>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]